# Backbone collection.create not creating the model locally

Tags: backbone.js

I gave up finally. I have struggling to get this one to work but no luck. I simply have a collection.create call like this:

```
                    var createData = {
                        full_name : full_name,
                        email : email,
                        role_id : role_id
                    };

                    var that = this;
                    app.collections.teamMembers.create(createData,{
                        wait: true,
                        success : function(){
                            log("in success")
                        },
                        error : function(a,b,c){
                            log("in error")
                        }
                    })
```

The server is PHP and it returns the result like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array(
        "data" => $data,
        "meta" => $meta
    ));
```

In the above, the $data is actually the array("attr"=>"val", ...) which matches exactly how the model for this collection is defined.

The problem is that since I am not returning directly a JSON object similar to the original model, but using namespacing (data/meta), I use model.parse on the model like this:

```
parse : function(response){
        log(response, "inside model parse, this is the response from server")
        return response.data;
    },
```

ISSUE: The model doesn't get created on the client end. No 'add' event is fired. I am also using the wait:true option.

However, the model gets created on the local if:
- I don't use wait:true
- I use wait true but return the exact JSON model from server, with no name spacing.

I WANT to use wait:true as well as namespacing. Please help :(

Comment: Also, after the server responds, it DOES get into the success callback!

Comment: I don't have default hash in the model, is that necessary?

Comment: UPDATE: Another thing I noted is that the .create method DOES return a valid model (i tested it by saving it to the window and then using console I read its value). However, the new model still isn't getting inserted! STRANGE!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to fix it, I was overriding backbone collections and models in my bootstrap to have a loading state which I am not using anyway. So I commented out that whole code. Now it works fine. this was the code in my bootstrap that I commented out:

```
// OVERRIDINGS AND SETTINGS
    //----------------------

    // Adding close method to all views
    Backbone.View.prototype.close = function() {
        if (this.onClose) {
            this.onClose();
        }
        _.each(this.childViews, function(childView){ 
            childView.close();
            delete childView;
        })
        this.remove();
        this.unbind();
    };

    // Adding loading state to every model and collection
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.loading = false;
    Backbone.Model.prototype.isLoading = false;

    // Set isLoading to true when fetch starts
    var oldFetch = Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch;
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch = function(options) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        oldFetch.call(this, options);
    }
    Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch = function(options) {
        this.isLoading = true;
        oldFetch.call(this, options);
    }

    // Turn off isLoading when reset
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.on('reset', function(){
        this.isLoading = false;
    })
    Backbone.Model.prototype.on('reset', function(){
        this.isLoading = false;
    })
```